# How to use a SAS drive as an external hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sas

I am not a server guy. I have few external hard disks lying around. Googling around I found those are SAS drives. I want to convert it into an external hard drive for personal use (I'm planning to connect it to the router that has USB 3.0 ). How to connect these drives to the router through USB or ethernet? Any help would be welcome. The hard disk is in the image.

[image]

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/376780/how-can-i-connect-a-sas-drive-to-usb related and worth a read. Basically you can't.

Comment: Give it to a computer recycling place and ask for a used SATA drive or USB External Drive in return.  It can't be that big of a drive if it is just laying around and SAS.  I'm guessing 300 GB or less.  A SATA of comparable size will be simpler and cost next to nothing.  As @JourneymanGeek mentioned, it is near impossible to do what you want without a full on workstation used to provide an external interface or some rube Goldberg mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I came across two SAS to USB adapters that seem to have the necessary SAS controller as well as physical connectors; however the cost is going to be prohibitive for many.

Ebay $600
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Reader-Cable-SAS-to-USB-3-0-Adapter-Universal-Converter/192743009670?hash=item2ce060ed86:g:VeIAAOSwcOZcAV3g:rk:1:pf:0

Other  ?$
https://letmelinkusb.com/sas-to-usb-converter/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6eh9kgaWy0

Comment: FYI, folks: when I search Amazon for "Computer Hard Drive Enclosures SAS" I get a bunch of results (23).  ALL 23 are false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Just got my converter for $5.50 from aliexpress **SFF-8482 SAS 22 Pin to 7 Pin** - not work for anybody when read comments

- is **not working** only detect drive but when init try change MBR GTP
  failed (Win)
- drive spin - make whining noise
- ended up with my laptop power supply stop working and run on battery. After restart connect different power supply and then back to main original its working again

[image: SASSATAFAILED]

Found this one maybe its work:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6eh9kgaWy0

https://letmelinkusb.com/sas-to-usb-converter/

___ UPDATE _____

Connected to different HDD Enclosure but this time partition are not detected

[image]

Comment: The reason for this is that it is a passive converter, it doesn't convert the signals.  SAS drives run at different signal voltages to SATA.  SAS controllers will usually speak SATA as well, but SAS drives cannot talk to a SATA controller.  Since most USB adapters only talk SATA, they will not work with SAS drives.

Comment: Any way just switch to SSD ;) but my power supply for my laptop was burned + power cable. So never try again.

Comment: I'm already using SSDs but that doesn't help me plug in a SAS tape drive via USB for backups onto LTO tape :-P

Comment: When i press "OTB" button (stupid idea) my power corridor/charger get burned. Buy some old server and import array or replace everything with SSD on RAID 0 at last easy to recovery and SAS data recovery cost really lot of money

Answer (score -2):

Startech make a $30 drive bay to turn anything into SATA, ie load SAS drive in the front and takes standard SATA out the back. That will speak fluent PC. Then you can do SATA to USB 3.0. Crazy I know, but very doable despite what other people have said. No judgement on whether you really want to be doing this and for what cost.

Comment: Do you have a link for this?  I've looked through their products but I can't find anything that converts SAS into SATA for $30.

Answer (score -3):

You can use pretty much any HDD enclosure, which you can find on sites such as Newegg or Amazon. The keyword to search for is "External Hard drive enclosure".

Just make sure to choose SAS interface rather than SATA.

Here is a sample: https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100008040%20600006291

Comment: Its also a different interface. You can plug in a sata drive into SAS connectors but not SAS drives into sata connectors

Comment: You're right, thank you for pointing that out. I clarified my answer.

Comment: None of those enclosures support the requested USB or ethernet

Comment: Not ethernet of course, but certainly USB 3.0 .

Comment: That newegg search considers SATA & SAS equivalent... but it seems like they're not